# Include results of a Paypal button generator in post without copy/paste

Tags: php, jquery, html, paypal

I own a locally exclusive trade form for people to sell items to others locally.  I want to have an option to include a Paypal "Buy Now" button in new posts but I'm stuck at how to include the button in a new post without having the user manually copy/past the HTML. I have made a simple Paypal button generator with a checkbox and jQuery to display form fields if checkbox is checked.  Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48Agy/)

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" /> Add a "Buy Now" Paypal button 
</form>
<div id="extra">
<form action="includes/paypal_button.php" method="post">
Paypal account email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Short item description: <input type="text" name="item" /><br />
Price for item (all amounts are in USD): <input type="text" name="amount" /><br />
Tax amout: <input type="text" name="tax" /><br />
Shipping and handling: <input type="text" name="shipping" />
<input type=submit value="Create Paypal button!">
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra").css("display","none");
        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme").click(function(){
        
        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra").hide("fast");
        }
      });
    
    });
</script>
```

The controller form is in a separate php script, paypal_button.php

HTML

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($_POST["email"]))?>" >  
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($_POST["item"]))?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($_POST["amount"]))?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($_POST["tax"]))?>">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(($_POST["shipping"]))?>">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

So should I include the controller(the button to print) in a php if statement that will print the button in new form posts?  It would be highly appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So I'm assuming this is something like Craigslist.  And you're giving sellers an option to create a PayPal button.  Wouldn't you have to save the post data from your form into a DB?  Which at that point, would be easy to recreate the button on the seller's Item Page.  Otherwise, from what I'm seeing... the PayPal button only shows up once.

Comment: That's  interesting.  I've actually thought of inserting the user's paypal info into my db then selecting and printing where I want it to go.  The only problem is I wouldn't want to keep their info in my db.  So if I print the button and then delete the user's Paypal info from my db, would the button still be functional?

Comment: That kind of data is dynamic and would have to be stored somewhere.  So that can be a DB, file, or application scope - DB being the most logical.  If you really don't want to keep the data for some reason, just delete it after the post/item expires.

Comment: If all your storing is sale items' pricing, shouldn't be much of a security risk. I mean, the whole purpose of a craigslist-type website is promoting the sale prices so no big secrets there. User's email address would be the most sensitive required by Paypal, but you probably have that on file anyways from when users signed up. I'm no security expert, just my 2 cents :)